# Python library to parse SQL create statements

Tags: python, oracle-database

I have a requirement of reading Oracle create statement in a file and gather all Metadata (Table name, column name, its datatypes etc).

I have tried following but no luck so far:
1) Used twextpy (pip install failed and I'd to download full version from below)
https://github.com/apple/ccs-twistedextensions/blob/master/twext/ 
Failed to use as few code set is not available

2) Used sqlparse but appears very tedious to extract information.

Please kindly suggest any python library which can help me read SQL and extract metadata information.